# No ads found for ad unit - Mopub_flutter

Tags: flutter, mopub

I'm trying to implement Mopub into my Flutter project but I have some issues related to [mopub_flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/mopub_flutter).

MopubAdManager class contains the IDs of Mopub stuff.

This is my initState:

```
  void initState() {
try {
  MoPub.init(MopubAdManager().publisherId, testMode: true).then((_) => {
        loadRewardedAd(),
      });
} catch (e) {
  print('exception: ${e.toString()}');
}
super.initState();
```

This is the loadRewaredAd function

```
  void loadRewardedAd() {
videoAd = MoPubRewardedVideoAd(MopubAdManager().rewardedAd, (result, args) {
  setState(() {
    var rewardedResult = '${result.toString()}____$args';
  });
  print('$result');
  if (result == RewardedVideoAdResult.GRANT_REWARD) {
    print('Grant reward: $args');
  }
}, reloadOnClosed: true);
```

This is how I call the function inside a button with onPressed

```
                              RaisedButton(
                              child: Text('Show Video'),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                videoAd.load();
                                var result = await videoAd.isReady();
                                print('Is Ready $result');
                                if (result) {
                                  videoAd.show();
                                }
                              },
                            ),
```

Before touching the button, Mopub prints that line in console:

```
I/MoPub   (30148): [com.mopub.network.TrackingRequest$1][onResponse] SDK Log - Successfully hit tracking endpoint: https://ads.mopub.com/m/open
```

After touching the Show Video button that appears in console:

```
    V/AudioManager(30148): querySoundEffectsEnabled...
I/MoPub   (30148): [com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubRewardedVideoManager][fetchAd] SDK Log - Loading rewarded ad request for ad unit 40825097a53247c5a91f9775d3f54298 with URL https://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=6&id=40825097a53247c5a91f9775d3f54298&nv=5.15.0&dn=HUAWEI%2CPOT-LX1%2CPOT-LX1&bundle=com.example.anket&z=%2B0300&o=p&cw=1080&ch=2259&w=1080&h=2340&sc=3.0&ct=2&av=1.0.0&abt=%7B%22tapjoy%22%3A%7B%22token%22%3A%221%22%7D%7D&ifa=mp_tmpl_advertising_id&dnt=mp_tmpl_do_not_track&tas=mp_tmpl_tas&mid=mp_tmpl_mopub_id&gdpr_applies=0&force_gdpr_applies=0&current_consent_status=unknown&vv=4&vver=1.3.4-Mopub&mr=1
I/MoPub   (30148): [com.mopub.network.AdLoader][fetchAd] Ad requesting from AdServer: https://ads.mopub.com/m/ad
I/MoPub   (30148): {"vv":"4","nv":"5.15.0","mid":"e458ffd9-db59-4753-9878-c923a99ef3fc","dn":"HUAWEI,POT-LX1,POT-LX1","sc":"3.0","current_consent_status":"unknown","vver":"1.3.4-Mopub","id":"40825097a53247c5a91f9775d3f54298","bundle":"com.example.anket","gdpr_applies":"0","ch":"2259","ifa":"fe6b229f-fa21-4367-ac77-f8437ef7ebb6","mr":"1","tas":"authorized","h":"2340","force_gdpr_applies":"0","dnt":"0","o":"p","ct":"2","abt":"{\"tapjoy\":{\"token\":\"1\"}}","cw":"1080","av":"1.0.0","v":"6","w":"1080","z":"+0300"}
I/flutter (30148): Is Ready false
I/MoPub   (30148): [com.mopub.network.MultiAdResponse][parseSingleAdResponse] Ad server responded with:
I/MoPub   (30148): {"content":"","metadata":{"x-adtype":"clear","x-backfill":"clear","x-refreshtime":60}}
I/MoPub   (30148): [com.mopub.network.AdLoader$1][onErrorResponse] Ad server responded with:
I/MoPub   (30148): No ads found for ad unit.
I/flutter (30148): Flutter mopub rewarded method error
I/flutter (30148): RewardedVideoAdResult.ERROR
```

Other Ad types such as banner, interstitial shows the same error.

I have created the ad units and copied the Ids to the MopubAdManager class but yet no ads appear in the app. I have tested the test Ids they work perfectly.

Did I skip something?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @GibreelAbdullah I suspect that it is about the where app runs regionally. So if you are in somewhere that does not use MoPub ad service for publishing ads, you may not be able to show MoPub ads in the application.

Comment: so after the deployment you started receiving revenue?

Comment: Nope. My region does not have any publishers in Mopub as I know. So I did not receive any ads in my app and did not get any revenue.